# Split Testing Facebook Posts Made by App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ab-testing, facebook-analytics

We run a few facebook contest websites than post a lot of user triggered facebook posts. We've been attempting to improve the performance of our posts, so we've trying to to find a way to split test our posts sent by the servers.

Initially, we thought that we'd be able to pass the `ref` attribute and then use that to segment the metrics given by FB, but it seems like you can only using the `ref` value with certain javascript widgets.

I have looked through the documentation but I can't find anything that I could use to make statistically relevant experiment:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/app_insights

Has anyone implemented anything similar? I have tried googling but all the results appear to be regarding page posts/ads.

Any help would be massively apppreciated!